# After converting to numeric still not in numeric format in R

Tags: r, numeric

I have an issue in converting data into the numeric format.

```
str(DfFilter)
```

output

```
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ InstanceType      : chr  "  c1.xlarge" "  c1.xlarge" "  c1.xlarge" "  c1.xlarge" ...
 $ ProductDescription: chr  "  Linux/UNIX" "  Linux/UNIX" "  Linux/UNIX" "  Linux/UNIX" ...
 $ SpotPrice         : num  0.052 0.0739 0.0747 0.0751 0.0755 ...
 $ ymd_hms(Timestamp): POSIXct, format: "2021-05-16 06:26:40" "2021-05-16 00:58:55" "2021-05-16 06:46:50" ...
 $ Timestamp         : 'times' num  06:26:40 00:58:55 06:46:50 14:17:55 19:07:09 ...
  ..- attr(*, "format")= chr "h:m:s"
```

but when i run to check for numeric values as follow

```
is.numeric(DfFilter)
[1] FALSE
```

why is that so. Kindly help in understanding this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DfFilter` is a dataframe. Therefore, it can't be numeric

Comment: You can test each column in turn to see if its numeric, - e.g. try `sapply(DfFilter, class)` - but as @MonJeanJean says, a dataframe is not numeric itself.

Comment: I only want to keep numeric walue i my dataset
`DfModel<- DfFilter %>%
  keep(is.numeric)%>%
  gather()`
but the output is not what is expected.

Comment: `
 
key
<chr>
value
<dbl>
1 SpotPrice 0.0520  
2 SpotPrice 0.0739  
3 SpotPrice 0.0747  
4 SpotPrice 0.0751  
5 SpotPrice 0.0755  
6 SpotPrice 0.2032 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `purrr` package and based on the comments:

```
DfModel <- DfFilter %>% 
  purrr::keep(.p = function(x) is.numeric(x))
```

It will keep only the numeric variables

Comment: yes it works, but what is '.p'

Comment: `.p` is short for predicate function. It means it applies this function and keep the variables where the output of this function is `TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

`Filter` with `is.numeric` could be used to get only `numeric` columns.

```
Filter(is.numeric, DfFilter)
#  a   c
#1 1 2.2
```

Another way to keep only numeric value in a `data.frame` the result of `is.numeric` used in `sapply` could be used for subsetting with `[`:

```
DfFilter[sapply(DfFilter, is.numeric)]
#  a   c
#1 1 2.2
```

Example dataset:

```
DfFilter <- data.frame(a=1, b="b", c=2.2)
```